# Android Material Design Simple Menu

Tags: android, menu, material-design

I'm wanting to create the simple menu as defined in:

https://material.google.com/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus

I've seen online that a `PopoverMenu` is an option, however that doesn't cover the emitting element and doesn't align the current selected item over the emitting element. What type of view would be used for the Material Design Simple Menu?

Comment: https://github.com/takisoft/preferencex-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's just a [PreferenceScreen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) with material design elements. thats how it would look with a device running 5.0 and up

Comment: So from what I'm reading, I can't have just a `ListPreference` as one of the children views? I would have to use a `PreferenceActivity` or a `PreferenceFragment`. I was hoping I could just use that simple menu in one of my views.

Comment: ListPreference is a dialog that comes up. You create a PreferenceActivity/PreferenceFragment then create a xml file with all your options you want

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I could add it into a `DialogFragment` but doesn't seem possible.